Libtorrent ImportError in python Windows
I'm trying to download torrent in python using torrentp but it has a dependencies to libtorrent.
I tried to run this code
import asyncio
from torrentp import TorrentDownloader
torrent_file = TorrentDownloader("magnet:...", '.')
# Start the download process
asyncio.run(torrent_file.start_download()) # start_download() is a asynchronous method 

But I'm getting this error:
D:\Torrent\Media\Script>python torrent.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Torrent\Media\Script\torrent.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torrentp import TorrentDownloader
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torrentp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .torrent_downloader import TorrentDownloader
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torrentp\torrent_downloader.py", line 4, in <module>
    import libtorrent as lt
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found.

I've read several post about libtorrent but so far nothing has fixed it:

Reinstalling Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
Reinstall libtorrent and torrentp

I installed libtorrent using pip install libtorrent and pip install torrentp
I also tried to install the packages from github and do python setup.py build and python setup.py install but I'm getting this:
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Both from build and install

The torrentp package already contains the libtorrent dependency, no need to install it separately. By blindly installing and reinstalling everything you probably transformed your OS into a hardly recoverable mess. Next time use a virtual environment to be able to easily recover from most of the mishaps.

@Jeyekomon I've just installed torrentp with pip install torrentp and then tried to run the python script but it didn't work. So I've read the error and tried to reinstall libtorrent...

I recommend checking this package on Github: Torrent-To-Google-Drive-Downloader
